# How to make 2 tables same size even if columns and rows are in different numbers. And how to merge rows with columns

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a problem because I want these two tables to have the same size even though they have a different number of columns (as in the picture). I also want the last row in the second column to have the same size as the rest. I also need to connect the first row in the first table with the first columns of the rest of the rows. Does anyone have an idea?

I tried setting width and height but it didnt work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 200px;
            height: 300px;
        }
        td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 70px;
            height: 30px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="tabela">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>DoM</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>100</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="tabela">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Szkola</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="tabela">
        <tr>
            <td>200</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Please provide a picture of what this is supposed to look like. At present your requirement is a little unclear to me.

Comment: Does `table-layout: fixed;` help at all? https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/KKYpOGa?editors=1100